# First time cooking/eating asparagus, what's the best way to cook it?

Tags: potatoes, salmon, asparagus, hollandaise

So I'm going to bake some salmon fillets today  along with potatoes and hollandaise sauce. 
I always see asparagus being eaten with salmon so I went and bought some. Ive never made it before so I was wondering what the quickest and easiest way is to cook it? 
Would it be alright to cook it in a pan with olive oil and some garlic?

P.s. I also have some button mushrooms. I'm thinking is just sautéing them on olive oil.if anyone has any ideas please do tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as it's a recipe request, and also opinion based.

Comment: That should work.  Be careful as they can quickly go from firm to mushy.

Comment: @GdD it's more about cooking techniques and actual recipes.

Answer (score 1):

Snap the hard part of the asparagus, bend the asparagus and it should snap at some point near the harder part.

Use a peeler to peel the out skin of the stem, the outer skin is tougher, more fibrous.

In all situation, be careful not over cook them, then should still have some bite to them.

Steam or boil, use them whole in this situation.
Pan fry in oil and/or butter, I prefer cutting them in smaller pieces.
BBQ or grill them whole (my preferred way).

Comment: If you snap them then you don't need to peel also. If you don't snap them then peel about the bottom half to get rid of the fibrous part.